# Constructing an oscillating function with a nonnegative integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

It is a well-known fact that if $f(t)\geq0$ for $t\geq0$, then $\int_{t}^{\infty}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\geq0$ for $t\geq0$ provided it exists. I am looking for a counter example of the reverse statement. How can we constract an oscillating continuous function such that $\int_{t}^{\infty}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\geq0$ for $t\geq0$ provided it exists?

Comment: If you don’t ask for an oscillating function, I think $f(s)=(s-0.5)e^{0.5-s}$ would be a good example.

Comment: @Szeto Thank you for the comment but oscillation is crutial here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B>0$ and $r\in(0,1)$ such that $rA\geq{}B$.
Suppose that $f(t)\geq0$ for $t\in\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}[2k,1+2k]$,
and $f(t)\leq0$ for $t\in\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}[1+2k,2+2k]$.
Suppose further that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[]
\int_{0+2k}^{1+2k}f(s)\mathrm{d}s={}&r^{k}A\quad\text{for}\ k=0,1,\cdots,\\
\int_{1+2k}^{2+2k}f(s)\mathrm{d}s={}&-r^{k}B\quad\text{for}\ k=0,1,\cdots.
\end{aligned}\label{eq1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
We will show that $F(t):=\int_{t}^{\infty}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\geq0$ for $t\geq0$.

- Let $t=1+2k$ for some $k=0,1,\cdots$, then
  \begin{align}
  F(1+2k)={}&\sum_{\ell=k}^{\infty}\int_{1+2\ell}^{2+2\ell}f(s)\mathrm{d}s
  +\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{\infty}\int_{2\ell}^{1+2\ell}f(s)\mathrm{d}s\nonumber\\
  ={}&-\sum_{\ell=k}^{\infty}r^{\ell}B
  +\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{\infty}r^{\ell}A\nonumber\\
  ={}&-\frac{Br^{k}}{1-r}
  +\frac{Ar^{k+1}}{1-r}\nonumber\\
  ={}&\frac{r^{k}}{1-r}(rA-B)\geq0.\nonumber
  \end{align}
- Let $t\in[2k,1+2k]$, then $F(t)=\int_{t}^{1+2k}f(s)\mathrm{d}s+F(1+2k)\geq0$.
- Let $t\in[1+2k,2+2k]$, then $F(t)\geq{}F(1+2k)\geq0$.

---

Now, we give an explicit definition of a function satisfying the properties in \eqref{eq1} with $A=1$, $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=rA$.
Define $f(t)=2(-1)^{\lfloor{}t\rfloor}\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)^{\lfloor\frac{t+1}{2}\rfloor}(1-|2\{t+1\}-1|)$ for $t\geq0$,
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $\{\cdot\}$ denote the integer and the fractional parts, respectively.
Here is a graphic of the function defined above.

[image: Graphic of $f$]

---

Another example is the following $g(t):=\frac{\sin(t\pi)}{2^{\lfloor\frac{t+1}{2}\rfloor}}$. See the next figure.

[image: Graphic of $g$]

---

Thanks to **saulspatz** for correcting the first picture.

Comment: From the graph, it sure looks like the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ will be negative.

Comment: @saulspatz See the proof for the case $t=1+2k$, which shows that the integral over $[1,\infty)$ is $0$.

Comment: I was calling the proof into question.  The function is piecewise linear.  In the graph, from 1 to 2 we see a triangle with base $1$ and directed height $-1$, so area $-1/2$ from $2$ to $3$ a triangle of area $1/4$ and so on.  Thus, the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ is $-1/2+1/4-1/8+\dots=-1/3.$

Comment: @saulspatz The proof is correct but the example function seems to be wrong. I will fix it.

Comment: Makes sense.  I just glanced at the proof and jumped to the graph.

Comment: Another simple example is the following $f(t)=\frac{\sin(t\pi)}{2^{\lfloor\frac{t+1}{2}\rfloor}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite satisfying function:
$$f(s)=e^{k \frac{\sin(s)}{s+1}}-1$$.

When you plot the graph of it, I think it is obvious enough(for a large enough $k$) to see the requirements are met.

Well, I would like to tell you how I came up with this function.

Initially, $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ might be a good candidate. Indeed, I suspect that this may also satisfy the requirements.

To make the integral be positive, then I looked for a function which produces large number when the argument is positive and small for negative arguments. That’s what $e^x-1$ does!

Then, the composition of these two functions, with the magnifying constant, is exactly what you want.

I think this continuous function is what you really want, instead of a piecewise function.

Comment: You may see that **saulspatz**'s concern apply for your function. If you integrate your function from $[(2k+1)\pi,\infty)$, you will end up with a negative value since integral over the intervals of the form $[(2k+1)\pi,(2k+2)\pi]$ is negative...